What are the irreducible representations of $A_3$?
I've got some notes saying the Character table of the alternating group $A_3$ is given as in the attached image. I can't seem to figure out what the representations $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are supposed to be.
On $S_3$, it made sense to me that one can find irreducible representations on the invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{C^3}$, $V_1= sp(1,1,1)$ and $V_2 = $ { $ (x_1, x_2, x_3)| x_1+x_2+x_3 = 0$ }. Additionally, one can find the sign-representation.
For $A_3$, since all permutations are even, the sign-representation should be (equivalent to) the trivial representation. What are the other two? The $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ - exponential looks a whole lot like rotating a triangle, but what is the invariant subspace? I can't figure out any intuition for this.
$A_3$ character table" />

$\chi(1)=1$ for all of these characters, so the reps are 1-dimensional. Fitting, as $A_3$ is cyclic of order three.

The subspaces of $V_2$ are spanned by $(1,\omega,\omega^2)$ and $(1,\omega^2,\omega)$ respectively. Here $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Have you searched for the rep/character theory of cyclic groups? Or the discrete Fourier transform (which amounts to almost the same thing).
